# How to get actual client IP addresses with Express.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ip

I am running a Node.js server on Heroku with Express.js and I'm trying to get the actual IP address of the clients making requests to my server. However, due to the configuration of Heroku's network, I'm getting the IP address of Heroku's reverse proxy instead of the client IPs.

The main reason I need the client's IP address is because I'm using the [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) package to mitigate the risk of DDOS attacks. Here is the configuration of my rate limiter:

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
); 

const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 1000, // 1 minute
  max: 15, // limit each IP to 15 requests per windowMs
  message: "Woah! Slow down there cowboy. You can try again in 2 minutes.",
  onLimitReached: async function(req, res, options) {
    try{
      console.log(`Rate limit exceeded for IP: ${req.ip}`);

      if(req.ip){
        const geoInfo = await getGeoInfo(req.ip); // function to get geolocation info
        //sending slack hook containing ip
      }else{
        //sending slack hook without ip
      }
    }catch(err){
      console.error('[E353]',err);
    }
  }
});

app.use(limiter);
```

I have already tried setting 'trust proxy' to 1 in my Express.js configuration (as suggested in [this StackOverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494060/express-rate-limit-not-working-when-deployed-to-heroku).

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

I've been reading through the [Express.js guide for working behind proxies](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this.

Passing true instead of one worked.

```
app.set('trust proxy', true)
```

> If true, the client’s IP address is understood as the left-most entry in the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

You can read more from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)

Comment: That will appear to work, but it may lead you open to abuse by someone just setting `X-Forwarded-For: randomIP()` on each request. I don't know if Heroku filters something like that out; you should test it and see. 

Most likely, you just need a number higher than 1; try `app.set('trust proxy', 2)` or `3`, etc. See https://github.com/express-rate-limit/express-rate-limit/wiki/Error-Codes#err_erl_permissive_trust_proxy and https://github.com/express-rate-limit/express-rate-limit/wiki/Troubleshooting-Proxy-Issues for more info.

Comment: I switched to this later on too. Thanks for the insight.